# Joining two views

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case, view

I'm after some help please. I only use ms access and beginning to use SQL I have two views part1 and part2 I can't join them and get any results( I have the results from MS access ( see below results part ) . I need the same results to show in SQL  )
Thank you..

**View (part1)**

```
select Mvpr.Prefix, Mvpr.SubKey1 AS [Parkers Part Number], Mvpr.SubKey2 AS [Supplier Code], Mvpr.A12 AS [Supplier Part Number], vwProduct.Psupp as part1

FROM vwProduct INNER JOIN Mvpr ON vwProduct.KeyCode = Mvpr.SubKey1 

WHERE Mvpr.Prefix ='c'
```

**View (part2)**

```
SELECT dbo.RHeads.Document, RLines.Part, RHeads.Supp, RHeads.[DateTime], RLines.Unit, RLines.CQty, RLines.ClCost, RHeads.POrder, RHeads.Corder, RHeads.Branch as part2

FROM RHeads INNER JOIN RLines ON RHeads.Document = RLines.Document

WHERE RHeads.[DateTime] >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
```

**Result**

```
SELECT part1.Document, part1.Part  [Parkers Part], part2.[Supplier Part Number], part1.Supp  [Supplier Code], part1.Unit  [Unit Price], part1.CQty  [Qty Recieved], dbo.vwProduct.SI18  Surcharge, part1.POrder, part1.Corder, part1.Branch, part1.DateTime
FROM dbo.vwProduct INNER JOIN part2 INNER JOIN part1 ON part2.[Supplier Code] = part1.Supp AND part2.[Parkers Part Number] = part1.Part ON dbo.vwProduct.KeyCode = part1.Part
GROUP BY part1.Document, part1.Part, part2.[Supplier Part Number], part1.Supp, part1.Unit, part1.CQty, dbo.vwProduct.SI18, part1.POrder, part1.Corder, part1.Branch, part1.DateTime
```

Comment: `SELECT dbo` sounds to me you are using sql-server and not mysql.. please correct your tags.

Comment: please read this topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Based on your SQL in Result section, your View (part2) should be your part1 since columns such as Document, Part, etc. are coming from that and vice versa.

```
SELECT part1.Document, 
       part1.Part  [Parkers Part], 
       part2.[Supplier Part Number], 
       part1.Supp  [Supplier Code], 
       part1.Unit  [Unit Price], 
       part1.CQty  [Qty Recieved], 
       dbo.vwProduct.SI18  Surcharge, 
       part1.POrder, 
       part1.Corder, 
       part1.Branch, 
       part1.DateTime
  FROM dbo.vwProduct
 INNER JOIN part1    
    ON dbo.vwProduct.KeyCode = part1.Part
 INNER JOIN part2 
    ON part2.[Supplier Code] = part1.Supp 
   AND part2.[Parkers Part Number] = part1.Part 
 GROUP BY part1.Document, 
          part1.Part, 
          part2.[Supplier Part Number], 
          part1.Supp, 
          part1.Unit, 
          part1.CQty, 
          dbo.vwProduct.SI18, 
          part1.POrder, 
          part1.Corder, 
          part1.Branch, 
          part1.DateTime
```